# Break each new anagram of an array item to a new line

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am working an anagram generator and am trying to break off each new item in the array into a new line. The way this works is it slices each array item and loops through each character.

The output needs to be:

`cat, cta, act, atc, tca, tac,`

`bat, bta, abt, atb, tba, tab,`

`rat, rta, art, atr, tra, tar,`

But it is:

`cat, cta, act, atc, tca, tac, bat, bta, abt, atb, tba, tab, rat, rta, art, atr, tra, tar, splat, splta, spalt, spatl,...`

So far the code I have is this:

HTML:

```
<div id="anagrams"></div>
```

JS:

```
var arr = ['cat', 'bat', 'rat', 'splat'];

var allAnagrams = function(arr) {
var anagrams = {};
arr.forEach(function(str) {
    var recurse = function(ana, str) {
        if (str === '') 
            anagrams[ana] = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            recurse(ana + str[i], str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1));
        };
        recurse(' ', str); 
});
return Object.keys(anagrams);
}

document.getElementById("anagrams").innerHTML = (allAnagrams(arr));
```

To accomplish a new line per array item I basically want to check if the amount of the characters exceeds the amount of characters in the string/array item and if it does, insert a break into the HTML. I tried doing that by:

```
var arr = ['cat', 'bat', 'rat', 'splat'];

var allAnagrams = function(arr) {
var anagrams = {};
arr.forEach(function(str) {
    var recurse = function(ana, str) {
        if (str === '') 
            anagrams[ana] = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            recurse(ana + str[i], str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1));
            // check if string length is greater than the count and 
            // if it is, insert a break between the string
            if (i > str.length) {
                recurse(' <br>', str);
            }
        };
        recurse(' ', str); 
});
return Object.keys(anagrams);
}

document.getElementById("anagrams").innerHTML = (allAnagrams(arr));
```

However it still prints across a single line. Am I approaching this the correct way? I also tried using `ana` in place of `i` but I think I need to use `i` since that's the actual count - is that correct?

A jsfiddle can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/4eqhd1m4/1/

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it the anagrams of each array element per line? (cat would print "cat, cta, act, atc, tca, tac", the next line would be "bat, bta, abt, atb, tba, tab" for bat, etc?)

Comment: Haven't read your code, but I'd suggest simply finding all the anagrams, then rendering the results into the <div>. You could use a simple `document.getElementById("anagrams").innerHTML = anagrams.join("<br />");`

Comment: @Whothehellisthat The fiddle prints the string permutations into the document, the issue appears to be with adding the break lines/formatting.

Comment: @hodrobond yes correct, each item in the array needs to have it's own line. I updated my question to better explain

Comment: `i` can never be greater than `str.length` because of the for loop condition.

Comment: To me it makes sense to get all anagrams for 1 word, then display the result and put in your own break, then get the anagrams for the second word, etc.

Comment: @James I thought the same =). My answer was updated with a second example, returning the string permutations as array elements which add the breaklines using `Array.toString`, `String.split` and `String.join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would slightly restructure the anagram creation.

1. Anagrams is now a string.
2. Recurse no longer takes care of adding break lines. Considering you want a break per element, it's cleaner to add it in the `Array.forEach`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eqhd1m4/2/)

**Edit**

Adding a second jsfiddle to demonstrate the same behavior, except instead of using strings directly it returns an array (which gets split and rejoined using breaklines). It may be preferable to have the anagrams returned as an array.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eqhd1m4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you need ? All anagrams in different lines

```js
var arr = ['cat', 'bat', 'rat', 'splat'];

var allAnagrams = function(arr) {
var anagrams = {};
arr.forEach(function(str) {
    var recurse = function(ana, str) {
        if (str === '') 
            anagrams[ana] = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            recurse(ana + str[i], str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1));
            // check if string length is greater than the count and 
            // if it is, insert a break between the string
            if (i > str.length) {
                recurse(' <br \/>', str);
            }
        };
        recurse('  <br \/>', str); 
});
return Object.keys(anagrams);
}

document.getElementById("anagrams").innerHTML = (allAnagrams(arr));
```

```html
<div id="anagrams"></div>
```

Comment: No, each array item and it's anagrams needs to be on it's own line.